# Expand scale_x_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Plot and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPCmj.png)

How do I alter my code:

`scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(scale = 1e-6, suffix = "M"))`

to expand the scale to '$30M"? (See pic linked above)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code and image in your post, not as a linked screenshot. It easier for folks to help you this way

Comment: Will do; appreciate the input @AlexW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `limits` parameter

`scale_x_continuous(..., limits= c(0, 3e7))`